# Database design: split column with multiple data types

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I need to seggregate an old database field called `AMOUNT`, which allows users to store multiple types of numeric data (eg. decimals, integers, percentages) into the same column. The values can range from 100,000,000.00 to 0.00.

The values stored in `AMOUNT` can represent four different data formats:

- Amounts expressed in a local currency (e.g. values between 100,000,000.00 to 00.00 in euros, dollars, yen...)
- Integer amounts (e.g. integers between 0 and 12)
- Percentage amounts (e.g. values between 1 and 0.01)

Example:

```
CURRENCY_ID |   AMOUNT  |   TYPE      |
     1      |  1000000  |  Currency   |
     2      |  43234.33 |  Currency   | 
   NULL     |    12     |  Integer    |
   NULL     |   0.67    |  Percentage |
   NULL     |   0.58    |  Percentage |
   NULL     |    10     |  Integer    |
```

I have come up with the following design suggestions:

1. Create a new column called `TYPE_ID`, which indicates the data type ID (i.e. 1 = Amount expressed in local currency, 2 = integer amount, 3 = percentage amount) and link it to a separate table that containing all possible type IDs.

   ```
   CURRENCY_ID |  TYPE_ID |  AMOUNT
        1      |     1    |  1000000 
        2      |     1    |  43234.33
      NULL     |     2    |    12
      NULL     |     3    |    0.67
      NULL     |     3    |    0.58
      NULL     |     2    |    10
   ```

The problem I see with this is, however, that the amounts in the column `AMOUNT` still represent different formats (large integers and small decimals) and thus are not uniform.

2. Create a new column for each data type (i.e. `AMOUNT_LOCAL_CURRENCY`, `AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE`, `AMOUNT_INTEGER`) and store values of `AMOUNT` into corresponding columns.

   ```
   CURRENCY_ID |  AMOUNT_LOCAL_CURRENCY | AMOUNT_INTEGER | AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE
        1      |       1000000          |     NULL       |      NULL
        2      |       43234.33         |     NULL       |      NULL
      NULL     |         NULL           |      12        |      NULL
      NULL     |         NULL           |     NULL       |      0.67
      NULL     |         NULL           |     NULL       |      0.58
      NULL     |         NULL           |      10        |      NULL
   ```

The problem with this is that the number of data formats can increase, which would mean adding a new column each time a new format is created.

Local currencies have an own identifier table already in place.

What would be a suitable and scalable design to distinguish the various types of data in the AMOUNT column?

Thank you in advance!

Markus

Comment: What is the problem with original table? Although it's not ideal why do you need changing it? Suggestion 1 logically is no different from original table. Suggestion 2 is a half way to having multiple tables. But in absence of bigger picture all solutions lack grounds.

Comment: Thanks Stoleg. I am mainly concerned about the fact that there are such different formats within the same column (currencies, percentages,  other measurement scales), which I find peculiar, since they are not directly measuring the same thing.

Comment: You seem to be reaching into EAV schema design.  Beware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *idea* of a database table is to store and retrieve different (read unrelated) values in different columns (fields) so that processing them would be easier and you don't get a crapload of IF statements every time you need to manipulate it.

It's *almost* always best to create a new column for each type of input. Handle display issue at display time, not in SQL.

From experience, `Option 2` is best

Answer (score 0):

Please implement this

Use CURRENCY_ID column of Local currencies identifier table and add more rows for integer (1001) and percentage(1002), whatever higher code may not be use in Currency master table in future.

```
currency master for sample

Currency_ID | Type
1           | dollar
2           | euro  
1001        | INT_Amt
1002        | PERC_AMT
```

> 2. your Amount table will reference currency_ID column in old way :

```
CURRENCY_ID |  AMOUNT
     1      |  1000000 
     2      |  43234.33
   1001     |   12
   1002     |   0.67
   1002     |   0.58
   1001     |   10
```